# Can EclipseLink create the database specified in persistence.xml?

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I'm working through the exercises in Beginning Java EE 7 except I'm trying to adapt them to use MySQL instead of Derby.  For the [chapter 4 JPA exercise](https://github.com/agoncal/agoncal-book-javaee7/tree/master/chapter04/chapter04-putting-together), I changed the persistence.xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

  <persistence-unit name="chapter04PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>org.agoncal.book.javaee7.chapter04.Book</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="chapter04Create.ddl"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" value="chapter04Drop.ddl"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chapter04DB"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="USER"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="PASS"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="insert.sql"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

  <persistence-unit name="chapter04TestPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>org.agoncal.book.javaee7.chapter04.Book</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="create.sql"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" value="drop.sql"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:memory:chapter0`enter code here`4DB;create=true"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="insert.sql"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Everything builds fine, and if I go to the db server and create the database, the jar runs fine.  But I'm trying to get EclipseLink to create the db at runtime (as the book implies that Derby will do), and if the db doesn't exist when I run the jar I get this error:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'chapter04DB'
```

How can I get EclipseLink to create a MySQL database at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, because the automatic creation of a *database* is a Derby feature, instead of the automatic creation of the *schema*, which can be performed by EclipseLink using

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
```

Comment: So, to use MySQL with JPA, I have to manually create the database before runtime? (which I've already confirmed works)

Comment: Exactly - we have a similar setting with PostgreSQL and we have to create the DB first, too.